# flutter project compilation failing with "Execution failed for task 'fluttertoast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'" AndroidX

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am answering my own question here because I solved it after many hours of searching. This is NOT an already answered question, so please don't tag it as such. I wish it was, it would've saved me hours of frustration.

Flutter project is failing with this error. Fluttertoast error.

```
??:   ?? ContextCompat
  ??: ? FluttertoastPlugin
2 ???

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* 

    Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 26s
    *******************************************************************************************
    The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
    See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
    *******************************************************************************************
    Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying issue is that the android.support.v4.Content.ContextCompat import in fluttertoastplugin.java can't resolve the symbol ContextCompat. This is a dependency issue.

The solution is to go to your flutter project's pubspec.yaml and find the  fluttertoast dependency and update it to the latest version (currently ^3.1.0)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
  sdk: flutter
  dropdown_formfield: ^0.1.0
  camera: ^0.5.2+1
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.0 <----- THIS ONE
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
  video_player: ^0.10.1
  latlong: ^0.6.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.11+1
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter_blue: ^0.5.0
  flutter_bluetooth_serial: ^0.0.5
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

Comment: for me it was flutter_sound: ^2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

In my case. I updated all dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all I did was run

```
flutter clean
```

and rerun project and everything worked fine.